# Named Route Includes Index

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

How do you remove the index from a named route?

**Routes**

```
<?php

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'reports/finance'), function () {
    Route::controller('/', 'Reports\Finance\HomeController', ['getIndex' => 'reports.finance']);
});
```

**View**

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('reports.finance', 'admin', ['captial-admin']) }}
```

**Generated URL**

```
/reports/finance/index/captial-admin
```

**What I want...**

```
/reports/finance/captial-admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the 'url' of your app/config/app.php if there is 'index' there?

Comment: theres no index there... im not sure it can be done without modifying the core? its rather anoying :(

Answer (score 0):

You could be more explicit in your routes definitions.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'foo'], function(){
    Route::get('bar/baz', ['uses' => 'SomeController@getIndex', 'as' => 'route.name']);
});
```

Beats editing the core.